# Eclipse package not found when compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I've imported the JAXB package into my class file and configured the build path to add the associated JARs. Now there are no errors visible in my code but when I try to compile the class it gives me an error saying the package is not found. Is there something else I need to define for it to see this package?

Comment: So, some unknown code causes some unknown error message to be displayed? How could we help?

Comment: All compile errors should show up in the editor, unless you're not building the project with Eclipse.

Comment: is it a maven, ant, whatever project or do you just add the jars as external jars to the classpath in eclipse? If so, this will only work if you build your project with eclispe (as @immibis) pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an ANT build file and found that the classpath refid was pointing to another lib folder so I moved the JARs to that one and it compiled without errors.